# Ajax request doesn't work in net core 2.2

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I have a `<a> element` with an `ajax` request attached to it. The request triggers a method in my `AdminController`, and should return a json with a boolean value. There is no data send with the ajax request to the back-end. If i try this code, it  What am I missing?

However, I get the full html of the page back.

My ajax call:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $(".pp-get-status").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Admin/GetAzFunctionForRefresh",
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (response) { 
                    console.log(response);
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert(error.status);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

My controller:

```
[HttpPost]
  public async Task<JsonResult> GetAzFunctionForRefresh()
{
    bool status = await _admin.CheckStatus(); // some business logic
    return Json(new { Message = status });
}
```

and the a element in the html

```
<a class="pp-get-status" title="Refresh for this resource">
<i class="fas fa-sync img-vhd"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: Silly question but are you sure that it is the full page you are getting back and not an exception page (which is usually in html)?

Comment: Yes, it is the full page with everything there. Also, I get a 200 OK code back, if I check the network tab in my dev tools of the browser. However, if I add a checkpoint in the method in my controller in Visual Studio, it doesn't get executed.

Comment: Ok, have you tried posting to the endpoint in postman (Or similar tool)? You might also want to try adding a leading / in your URL (so /Admin/GetAzFunctionForRefresh)

Comment: Sorry didn't see the bit about not hitting the endpoint... try the leading / to start off with. If you're break point isn't being hit then I'm not sure how you would get a page returned

Comment: Thank you, your suggestions lead me to the solution. I had as url /Admin/GetAzFunctionForRefresh but the method is not in my admin controller, but Home controller. Changing it to /Home/GetAzureFunctionForRefresh did the job. I get the correct response back. Silly mistake...

Comment: If you use the Url Helper you can make sure these sorts of urls are always correct with intellisense and compiler errors for being wrong. `@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName") `